# Expanding Text using <details> & <summary> HTML5 tags

Tags: html

I have a huge block of text that I only want to display so many characters before it shows a "view more" link.

So I did:

```
<p>Text being displayed when suddenly
<details>
<summary>View More</summary>
here comes the text to be expanded.</p>
</details>
```

This works, but it looks like this:

Text being displayed when suddenly
**View More**
here comes the text to be expanded.

So, it breaks the phrase with the summary tag in the middle.
I´ve been trying to make the text expand upwards or, in other words, making the summary appear below the expanded text, so that the phrase continues fluidly, but without success.

Tried moving the summary tag to the end, right before the closing details tag, but results are the same.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error and then digging deeper in research mode I came across a solution.

Turns out, the best way I could find to achieve this is through JQuery instead.

(Big thanks to Max, whoever/wherever you are, for this pen https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA/ that just saved me from trouble! - You may want to check it out to see, in action, what my question was all about, in case you´re wondering...)

So, following my example, I now have this:

```
<span class="more">Text being displayed when suddenly here comes the text to be expanded</span>
```

And that´s it for the Html part. I went for a span tag, but you could use a div the same way.

Now I only need to target that class via JQuery and determine how many characters I want it to display before it hides the text.

In my case, I went for 200 characters.

And here´s the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Configure/customize these variables.
var showChar = 200;  // How many characters are shown by default
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "VEJA MAIS >";
var lesstext = "MOSTRAR MENOS";


$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ ' </span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>  <a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
});
```

The "Show more" button is now handled through this code.

It´s a link really, and you can style it via its class ".more link" to have it be displayed any way you want. In my case I went for a button style, and used this CSS:

```
.morelink {
display: block;
float: right;
padding: .5em;
margin-top: .5em;
color: white;
background-color: rgb(63,72,71);
width: 50%;
text-align: center;    
}
```

Of course, width, margin and float parameters were decisions I made exclusively based on the layout I´m working with.

And, YES, I got what I wanted! Now the "Show More" button/link not only flows down with the text once it is revealed but also I can now change the text it shows once it does that (e.g. "show less") by simply addressing the appropriate var´s within the JQuery code (var moretext and var lesstext).

Awesome!

Hope this may help somebody else too.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display:inline
```

Example

```html
<p style="display:inline";>Text being displayed when suddenly
<details style="display:inline;">
<summary>View More</summary>
here comes the text to be expanded.
</details></p>
```

Comment: Hey, Daniel. Thanks for your feedback. However, unfortunately, display: inline; results are exactly the same I was getting before. "View More" still shows in the middle of the phrase. I want it to be at the bottom so that the text continues without interruptions.

Comment: Just adding to my last comment, when I said "exactly the same", I meant the summary tag was still shown in between the text before and inside <details></details>. Display inline does its trick, but it only prevents the line break. Any thoughts on how I can get "text before > text after > View More" instead of "text before > View More > text after"?

Answer (score 0):

You are not nesting the tags correctly, you open the `<p>` then open the `<details>` but then you are closing the `<p>`. I have updated my answer since I didn't know much about these two tags.

OK:

HTML5 provides the toggle function by default and the correct nesting of these tags including content is:

```
<details>
    <summary>Clickable preview or summary</summary>
    Your additional, long content goes here. This can be long paragraphs,    tables, basically everything.
</details>
```

That is enough to achieve the toggle with default browser functions, which you want I guess. As I said in my previous answer, it is not supported by Microsoft Edge/IE. You don't need the `<p>` tag for all this.

I did a simple thing: googled it : )

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/use-details-summary-elements

Comment: Your first nesting example is exactly what I did. The second one does not work as expected because the <p> tag that is supposed to be expanded is out of the <details> tag, so it is shown at all times. Thanks for pointing out that <summary> is unsupported by MS Edge/IE. But, bottom line is your suggestions do not work, unfortunately...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe that :P. We would need some more details about the CSS to drill deeper. Provide more information and I will have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, your first nesting example closes the <p> tag right after </details>. It was indeed different from my example. I did that, but the results were the same. :(

Comment: Tried copying the entire div I´m working with here, but it got too long for the comments section. What would be the best way to share this with you?

Comment: Wait a few minutes.. I'm building a local file right now

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer. Please mark the answer as correct if it did solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so the new info here is that I don´t need the <p> tag for the text that goes between <details>. 

However, using <p> or not, the result is the same. I stil get "text before details - SEE MORE/LESS - text after details" when what I´m trying to achieve is "text before details - text after details SEE MORE/LESS". 

Moving the <summary> tag after the content within <details> makes no difference either. 

I also Googled before coming here and went through SE´s answered questions on this topic. Guess you just didn´t quite undertsand what my question was. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question in first place, sorry for that :) But  I believe the effect that you would like to achive is not possible with this kind of markup. Sure it's easy to build something like this, but not with details/summary. I have just seen that you marked an answer as correct, but it's pretty hacky. Speaking for myself, this is the path to the dark side. Use another markup and you are good to go for a beer with Yoda and Luke.. ;)

Comment: Hey, loved the star wars analogy! LOL! The answer I marked as correct was provided by myself actually. I found this pen at codepen (link in the answer) and it did the trick. If I may ask, why do you think that´s hacky? I went from markup language into programming, yes, but it´s a pretty straight forward script based on the # of characters a given CSS class is supposed to display before it hides the rest of the text. Doesn´t seem like a Sith approach to me... But maybe that´s how the Dark forces work, right? Without letting you notice it until it´s too late! Humm...

Comment: Take a deep breath, feel the (HTML)-Force and ask yourself: Do I want this kind of solution for my layout? (HTML changes will make you writing script again.. etc.. ) You are right, this is how the dark side works ;) - May the (HTML)-Force be with you!