# How to prevent breaks between consecutive details elements?

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a paragraph that expands dynamically by clicking on summary tags, using only HTML/CSS:

```css
    div.textexpand {
        display: inline-block;
                background-color: grey;
    }
    div.textexpand > * {
        display: inline;
    }
    details, details[open] {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    details > span {
        display: inline;
    }
    details > summary {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
<div class="textexpand">
<span>Lorem ipsum</span>
<details>
    <summary>dolor</summary> 
    <span>sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</span>
</details> 
<span>sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam</span>
<details>
    <summary>voluptua.</summary>
    <span>
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
    sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
</details>
</div>
```

Result: the first `<details>` element expands as expected.
But as soon as the additional information of the `<details>` element overflows the surrounding `<div>`, the whole `details` element (summary and additional information) breaks to the next line (tested with Firefox 92).

Expected: [details contents (yellow) should always break at the border of the surrounding div box (grey)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i120u.png).

Is there a simple way to do this with CSS that I'm missing?

I wasn't able to pull it off using various values for `white-space` (no effect short of preventing line breaks altogether) and `break-after` (no effect), and I'm trying to avoid Javascript solutions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286914/expanding-text-using-details-summary-html5-tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070124), you can use `display: contents` instead of `display: inline`, but be aware of some possible undesired side effects.

You can also consider changing `<details>` and `<summary>` to something like `<abbr title="Your description here">`.

Comment: Using `details[open] {display: contents}` with `details, summary {display: inline}` seems to work in my case.